# Sorting in React Select

Tags: reactjs, sorting, select

I'd like to know if it is possible to set the sorting by alphabetical and number order. Here is my code, and it only does the alphabetical sorting but not the numeric one.

```
 resellerList.sort((a1, a2) => {
        const b1 = a1.resellerName.toLowerCase();
        const b2 = a2.resellerName.toLowerCase();
        if (b1 == b2) return 0;
        if (b1 > b2) return 1;
        return -1;
    })
```

[image: screenshot of the dropdown in alphabetical sorting]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution if the names always starts with *'client'* following a *number* as in your example.

```js
// input = 'client 6' then output = 6
const sliceAndParseInt = client => {
  const client = client.resellerName.toLowerCase()
  return parseInt(client.slice(6))
}

const sorted = resellerList.sort((a, b) => {
  if (sliceAndParseInt(a) > sliceAndParseInt(b)) return 1
  if (sliceAndParseInt(a) < sliceAndParseInt(b)) return -1
  return 0
})
```

Otherwise, names are not always following the same convention unlike your example, you should change all the numbers to an equal length, e.g. `1` to `01`;

```
'14' > '2' # return false
'14' > '02' # return true
```

Regards:)

Comment: but the names are not always start with client, what do I do? I tried your code but it gives an error saying client.toLowerCase is not a function

Comment: @Yuki , In this case, you could change the numbers to be with an equal width, by adding **0** to the left of the numbers like '**1**' to '**01**'  and use your own solution not what I posted.